# Element-wise power of scipy.sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, exponentiation

How do I raise a `scipy.sparse` matrix to a power, element-wise? `numpy.power` should, according to [its manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html#numpy.power), do this, but it fails on sparse matrices:

```
>>> X
<1353x32100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 144875 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> np.power(X, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../scipy/sparse/base.py", line 347, in __pow__
    raise TypeError('matrix is not square')
TypeError: matrix is not square
```

Same problem with `X**2`. Converting to a dense array works, but wastes precious seconds.

I've had the same problem with `np.multiply`, which I solved using the sparse matrix's `multiply` method, but there seems to be no `pow` method.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with numpy to tell you the answer, but your code doesn't contradict the documentation.  The second argument to numpy.power should not be a number, but another matrix.

Comment: It looks like it's calling the object's `__pow__` method, which is attempting to square the entire matrix, rather than doing it elementwise. That fails because, as it says, the matrix isn't square.

Comment: @RoundTower: actually, the second element should be an array, which it not the same as a matrix in Numpy, but a scalar is the same as a `(1,)` or `(1,1)` array for the purposes of `numpy.power` on a dense array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a little low-level, but for element-wise operations you can work with the underlying data array directly:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> X = scipy.sparse.rand(1000,1000, density=0.003)
>>> X = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(X)
>>> Y = X.copy()
>>> Y.data **= 3
>>> 
>>> abs((X.toarray()**3-Y.toarray())).max()
0.0
```

Answer (score 21):

I just ran into the same question and find that sparse matrix now supports element-wise power. For the case above, it should be:

```
 X.power(2)
```

Comment: Is this for python 2.7?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be true for python 3.6

Comment: it might depend on the format of a sparse matrix, for csr it seems to work