# Scipy gives wrong result for matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I am using `scipy` to do matrix multiplication of sparse matrix. For some reason, `.power()` method doesn't work for sparse matrix. I have checked it using three methods:

Here's my code:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse
```

**Method1: Plain matrix multiplication**

```
row = np.array([0, 3, 1, 0])
col = np.array([0, 3, 1, 2])
data = np.array([4, 5, 7, 9])
P1 = sp.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4))
#Method 1
P1.power(4).todense() #gives wrong result
```

**Result:**

```
matrix([[ 256,    0, 6561,    0],  #6561 isn't right
        [   0, 2401,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,  625]], dtype=int32)
```

**Method 2:**

```
P = P1.copy()
#calculate ^4
for loop in range(2):
    P = P.dot(P)
P.todense()
```

**Output**

```
matrix([[ 256,    0,  576,    0],
        [   0, 2401,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,  625]], dtype=int32)
```

**Method3**

```
P1.dot(P1).dot(P1).dot(P1).todense()
```

**Output:**

```
matrix([[ 256,    0,  576,    0],
        [   0, 2401,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,  625]], dtype=int32)
```

**Method 4:**

One can check the result at [this website (symbolab.com)](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-multiply-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D4%260%269%260%5C%5C%200%20%267%260%260%5C%5C%200%20%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%20%260%260%265%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5E%7B4%7D)

[image]

Other threads on this topic ([Element-wise power of scipy.sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431557/element-wise-power-of-scipy-sparse-matrix), [Matrix power for sparse matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702416/matrix-power-for-sparse-matrix-in-python)), focus on *how* to do matrix multiplication. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `p.power(2)` is "*element-wise* power". `9**4` = `6561`. The first thread you linked also says so (in the title even).

Comment: Thanks Zinki. If you could add an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `**` notation:

```
(P1**4).todense()
```

**Result:**

```
[[ 256    0  576    0]
 [   0 2401    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0  625]]
```

**EDIT:** Regarding why `.power()` doesn't return the expected result:

— as [Zinki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7305358/zinki) mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887351/scipy-gives-wrong-result-for-matrix-multiplication/52887581?noredirect=1#comment92688067_52887351):

> <sub>`p.power(2)` is "element-wise power". `9**4` = `6561`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks I'L'l. Very respectfully, the question isn't about `how` to do the multiplication, but about why am I getting an incorrect answer. I believe there are 50K ways to multiplication.

Comment: You're welcome! Zinki's comment more or less sums it up why you don't get the correct result.

Comment: Oh thanks...Just saw that...Wonderful. If you can edit your answer, I will accept it.